# Snort 2.9.15 fast install script?

Tags: bash, automation, snort

I am new in Linux and I will like to learn about Linux servers and security. I am already running an Apache Server and other small server to learn from.All I will like now is something to increase my security and  I just found out about Snort, but I have a problem.

Because I am new, i found it rather hard to compile every requirements and i keep encounter errors. I try a few tutorials but I keep receiving errors like:

```
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:6083: recipe for target 'doc/CMakeFiles/all_built_sources.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [doc/CMakeFiles/all_built_sources.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Every time when I install a new library , another one is missing and everything look like an never ending chain of errors.

It will be possible to create a script of some kind that install Snort 2.9.15 for me so I can start learning what I need and bypass all the installation problems?

I found a couple of scripts that already do this but I must create my own rules, this after I finish to setup my `snort.conf` file, witch is somehow hard for me at this point.

Also I will be able to make a fast security deployment for my own home network and increase my security more above average.

Answer (score 2):

The avalanche of problems that occur with snort is given the fact that most of exiting tutorials are giving instructions starting from the point that you already have most of the libraries and most important the correct version of them.

I will show you how to fully install snort as NIDS and start learning how to control it on a Debian based system (can be both Ubuntu or Debian). Please try to avoid Debian buster for the moment because is still contain some bugs and you may encounter later errors.

Any Ubuntu Server or Debian Stretch will be just great. Just download the image from the internet, and install it on your support (laptop/virtual machine).

On a fresh install make sure you have all your requirements installed on the latest version.
This is the list:

```
 gcc              

 make             

 libpcre3-dev     

 zlib1g-dev       

 libluajit-5.1-dev

 libpcap-dev      

 openssl          

 libssl-dev       

 libnghttp2-dev   

 libdumbnet-dev   

 bison            

 flex             

 libdnet
```

This is the command to install them all:

```
sudo apt-get install -y gcc make libpcre3-dev zlib1g-dev libluajit-5.1-dev libpcap-dev openssl libssl-dev libnghttp2-dev libdumbnet-dev bison flex libdnet
```

Once everything is installed I will ask you to make a folder where to work the install process.
Example:

```
sudo mkdir working-direcotry
cd working-directory/
```

Now, please download both DAQ and Snort fallowing the official recommendations from Snort.org

Currently you can paste the fallowing code:

```
sudo wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/daq-2.0.6.tar.gz && sudo wget https://www.snort.org/downloads/snort/snort-2.9.15.tar.gz && sudo tar xvzf daq-2.0.6.tar.gz && sudo tar xvzf snort-2.9.15.tar.gz
```

Enter in your daq folder:

```
cd daq-2.0.6
```

PLEADE DO NOT RUN  `./configure && make && sudo make install`

This is where most of the new people are getting lost into errors. If something is not installed correctly you will not see only the first error, but also the rest of errors cause by the first missing dependency.

Please run then one by one to ensure a proper error troubleshooting :

```
sudo ./configure  
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Now, please lave daq folder and go to snort

```
cd..
cd snort-2.9.15
```

Here do the same as on DAQ install and perfom each action separate.

```
sudo ./configure --enable-sourcefire 
sudo make 
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/snort /usr/sbin/snort
```

Please check your install with:

```
which snort
snort --version
```

Now you have fully install Snort will all its dependencies. All is left is to make the setting inside the system in order to properly allow Snort to function.

For security reasons you must create a special user inside your system, user that can be use later with a database or anything else that you may want to experiment with:

```
sudo groupadd snort
sudo useradd snort -r -s /sbin/nologin -c SNORT_IDS -g snort
```

Your misfortune with all the errors was the fact that Snort actually expect a certain folder structure inside your system, and nothing until now create it. So do it yourself and remember to give the correct user permission to each folder  :

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/snort/rules
sudo mkdir /var/log/snort
sudo mkdir /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
sudo chmod -R 5775 /etc/snort
sudo chmod -R 5775 /var/log/snort
sudo chmod -R 5775 /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
sudo chown -R snort:snort /etc/snort
sudo chown -R snort:snort /var/log/snort
sudo chown -R snort:snort /usr/local/lib/snort_dynamicrules
```

This is not all, you are still missing critical files from your `/etc/snort/` folder

Now you suppose to be in `snort-2.9.15` folder. Please type `ls`. You see the `etc` folder inside the `snort-2.9.15` folder? Go inside.

If lost just go to your `working-directory`, where you download the source codes for DAQ and Snort and type

```
# Access the correct 'etc' folder
cd snort-2.9.15/etc/

# Copy all missing files to the correct position inside the system.
sudo cp *.conf /etc/snort
sudo cp *.config /etc/snort
sudo cp *.map /etc/snort
```

ALL DONE.
Snort is FUNCTIONAL WITH ALL ITS FILES IN PLACE.

Unfortunately you can not validate the configuration just yet because you do not have any rules in place.
Please set the correct rules path inside your `/etc/snort/snort.conf` file

```
sudo nano /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Got to line 104 by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (undersocre)
You will find

```
# Path to your rules files (this can be a relative path)
# Note for Windows users:  You are advised to make this an absolute path,
# such as:  c:\snort\rules
var RULE_PATH .../rules
var SO_RULE_PATH .../so_rules
var PREPROC_RULE_PATH .../preproc_rules

# If you are using reputation preprocessor set these
# Currently there is a bug with relative paths, they are relative to where snort is
# not relative to snort.conf like the above variables
# This is completely inconsistent with how other vars work, BUG 89986
# Set the absolute path appropriately
var WHITE_LIST_PATH .../rules
var BLACK_LIST_PATH .../rules
```

Change everything to look like below (you can replace the entire section from the file)

```
# Path to your rules files (this can be a relative path)
var RULE_PATH /etc/snort/rules
var SO_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/so_rules
var PREPROC_RULE_PATH /etc/snort/preproc_rules

# Set the absolute path appropriately
var WHITE_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
var BLACK_LIST_PATH /etc/snort/rules
```

Save and exit.

Observe that we declare the absolute path to the folders. Now,please de-active all the rules from the configuration file. To do this paste the fallowing into console :

```
# Make a backup with all the rules activated. 

sudo cp /etc/snort/snort.conf /etc/snort/snort.original

sudo sed -i 's/include \$RULE\_PATH/#include \$RULE\_PATH/' /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

VALIDATE YOUR INSTALL

```
sudo snort -T -c /etc/snort/snort.conf
```

Well Done. Snort 100% functional. But no rules. From now, is about you to play with rules and add them into the configuration file. If something is not working just create another copy of `snort.original` and replace 'original' with 'conf'

As an extra, I create a script that make everything described above plus add an full set of rules ready to be tested. The rules set is not up to date, but will work just fine for your home security or learning purposes.

To use my script, please install git

```
sudo apt install git
```

Now, clone my repo into your `working-directory` , decompress the archive and runt the SFDS script

```
sudo apt install git 
sudo mkdir your-folder
cd your-folder
sudo git clone https://github.com/WillyWeiss/SnortFastDeploymentScript.git
sudo tar xvfz sourcecode.tar.gz
sudo chmod +x SFDS
sudo ./SFDS
```

Please fallow the git instructions to run your Snort.

Comment: Note that generally speaking, questions that are about software *installation* and not software *development* are off-topic on SO, and should be closed, not answered. See the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, particularly the final bullet point, "not about programming as [described in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Comment: ...for this question in particular, our sister site [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) may be a better fit; by my read, it's square in the middle of their https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic rules.

Comment: I will post it there as well, after the 40 minutes past. I can not post more often due to security reason, and I`m no robot:)). Thank you for this. I will relay like to share this and I do not want to be off-topic